# Windows Home Server locks me out from accessing shared files

Tags: windows-home-server

I try to access my windows homeserver `\\IKE\users\simon` which has always worked and it tells me the account is invalid.

I log in via remote desktop (with admin username) and check the settings and everything is fine but the account is locked. If I unlock it in `Computer Management > Users and groups` and try to log in again it just gets locked again.

No passwords have changed or anything like that.

Answer (score 2):

Turned out to be that after a 3 hour power outage the system clock on the server was off by 5 days. Windows apparently doesn't like this.

I have an HP MediaSmart server - or whatever its called - which is several years old now. Its odd that the time would be off by 5 days but fixing the time on the server fixed the problem.

Comment: Here's how to unlock the account if you have this problem - I'd recommend solution #2 - http://support.microsoft.com/kb/970207